# Is there anything wrong in this Javascript line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, html

my code is not working after adding style property, here it is:

```
$("#instaUser").append("<figure style='"display:inline "'><img id='"+i+"' src='"+data.data[i].profile_picture+"' alt='pic number "+i+"' height='"+200+"' width='"+200+"'> <figcaption>@"+data.data[i].username+"</figcaption></figure>");
```

could it be that i used the " in a wrong way?

Comment: Yes, it could. The syntax highlighting in your question is quite effective at revealing it.

Comment: Try eliminating parts of that example, one part at a time, until you get working output- then add the last thing you removed, and you'll have a better idea of where to start looking.

Comment: Yes, it's a static string, not a variable, so you don't need to close the `"` quotes in the same way as the others where you're appending the variables.  just `style='display:inline'` is fine here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We do help people, but we don't debug people's code.

Comment: i tried adding + sign in **style ='"+ dis..etc** but it still doesn't work

Comment: Thank you very much, the code is working now, but the images are still not inline :(

Comment: That's probably worth a separate question, with more details about your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need double quotes wrapping `display: inline`

This is correct:

```
$("#instaUser").append("<figure style='display:inline'><img id='"+i+"' src='"+data.data[i].profile_picture+"' alt='pic number "+i+"' height='"+200+"' width='"+200+"'> <figcaption>@"+data.data[i].username+"</figcaption></figure>");
```

Comment: I would add that `height='"+200+"' width='"+200+"'`is unnecessary also. No need to use the + if it's not a variable.